# How to unzip a file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, zip

I'm uploading a file to the server in Ruby on Rails

Normally, it's a text file and I save it in the model as a 'file' field in a Submission ActiveRecord with other fields such as title of submission.. etc.

However, the user can also submit a zip file. In this case the zipfile should unzipped and for each file in the zip a new Submission should be created with the same text fields, but current file.

How can I accomplish this?

I looked at unzip examples on the net, but most use a directory to unzip the files to. I'm not sure if I need that as in the current create method of SubmissionsController, a file object is received and I presume the path to save the file to is automatically generated when the Submission save method is called. So I was thinking that maybe I should unzip the zipfile in memory to get an array of file objects and then create a new Submission with each file object but same fields and then let ActiveRecord generate the file paths for each one when it saves them to the database.
I might be wrong here, because I'm kind of new to Rails and Ruby.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'd use the [rubyzip gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip). Specifically this part: https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/master/lib/zip/filesystem.rb

It creates an artificial file system in memory mirroring the contents of the zip file. Here's an example based of the example from the docs:

`Rubyzip interface changed!!! No need to do require "zip/zip" and Zip prefix in class names removed.`

```
require 'zip'

Zip::File.open("my.zip") do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each do |file|
    # do something with file
  end
end
```

In your case, just put the name of the uploaded tempfile where `my.zip` is in the example, and you can loop through the contents and do your regular operations on them.

Comment: I see, so how could I get an array of file objects from the zip file?

Comment: @bizso09, I just updated to show how to loop through the contents. There is also a simple tutorial explaning it here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/10/02/ruby-unzipping-a-file-using-rubyzip/

Comment: Unfortunately `file` is of type ZipEntry and not of type File, so I cannot save it with Submissions

Comment: @bizso09, see the docs and the exmample. You can extract the file from the ZipFile, like `zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)`

Answer (score 27):

From the RubyZip project page:

> Rubyzip interface changed!!! No need to do require "zip/zip" and Zip prefix in class names removed.

So, the example code from @ben-lee should be updated to something like this:

```
require 'zip'

Zip::File.open("my.zip") do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each do |file|
    # do something with file
  end
end
```

Answer (score 27):

## Extract Zip files in Ruby

Once you've installed the [`rubyzip`](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) gem, you can use this method to extract zip files:

```rb
require 'zip'

def extract_zip(file, destination)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

  Zip::File.open(file) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |f|
      fpath = File.join(destination, f.name)
      zip_file.extract(f, fpath) unless File.exist?(fpath)
    end
  end
end
```

**You use it like this:**

```rb
extract_zip(zip_path, extract_destination)
```

Comment: I don't know if it's been changed recently or not, but the `extract` method only takes one arg, and will throw an error if you give it two.

Comment: What's the reason behind the condition `unless File.exist?(fpath)`? Is that just to replicate behaviour of other tools?

Comment: @JonBurgess seems like it's to avoid replacing an existing file with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me:

```
gem install rubyzip
```

**`main.rb`**

```rb
require 'zip'

def extract_zip(file, destination)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

  Zip::File.open(file) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |f|
      fpath = File.join(destination, f.name)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(fpath))
      zip_file.extract(f, fpath) unless File.exist?(fpath)
    end
  end
end

extract_zip('file.zip', 'tmp')
```