# How to unzip a zip file containing folders and files in rails, while keeping the directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

I need to extract a zip file that containes many folders and files using rails `ziprails` gem. While also keeping the files and folders organized the way they where ziped.

This was not as straight forward as i though. Please see the solution i found beneath (added for future reference)

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/ruby-unzip-many-zip-folders-under-a-directory

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This worked for me. Gave the same result as you would expect when unzipping a zipped folder with subfolders and files.

```
Zip::Zip.open(file_path) do |zip_file|
  zip_file.each do |f|
    f_path = File.join("destination_path", f.name)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
    zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
  end
end
```

The solution from this site:
http://bytes.com/topic/ruby/answers/862663-unzipping-file-upload-ruby

Comment: For me it was `Zip::File` not `Zip::ZipFile`

Answer (score 11):

## Extract Zip archives in Ruby

You need the [`rubyzip`](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) gem for this. Once you've installed it, you can use this method to extract zip files:

```rb
require 'zip'

def extract_zip(file, destination)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

  Zip::File.open(file) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |f|
      fpath = File.join(destination, f.name)
      zip_file.extract(f, fpath) unless File.exist?(fpath)
    end
  end
end
```

**You use it like this:**

```rb
file_path   = "/path/to/my/file.zip"
destination = "/extract/destination/"

extract_zip(file_path, destination)
```

Comment: This is not just the same as the accepted answer. You even posted the same answer two times: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37195592/322020 that is against SO rules.