# Upload a zipped file and unzip it while maintaining the original directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, zip, unzip

I'm building a log parser app. I followed a tutorial on how to make an upload function, which worked. My `new.html.erb` for my upload function looks like this (the tutorial was tailored to accept resumes, so some of the methods from my code read `@resume`):

```
   <div class="container">   
       <% if @resume.errors.present? %>    
          <div>   
             <ul>   
                <% @resume.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>   
                   <li><%= msg %></li>   
                <% end %>
               </ul>   
          </div>   
       <% end %>   

   <div>   
      <%= form_for @resume, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>   
         <%= f.label :name %>   
         <%= f.text_field :name %>   
         <br><br>   
         <%= f.label :attachment %>   
         <%= f.file_field :attachment %>   
         <br>   
         <%= f.submit "Save" %>   
      <% end %>   
   </div>
```

My `resume.rb` looks like:

```
class Resume < ApplicationRecord
   mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader  

   validates :name, presence: true 
end
```

My `attachment_uploader.rb` looks like:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

As a next step, I'm trying to upload a zipped file containing multiple log files. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754883/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-containing-folders-and-files-in-rails-while-keeping-the/19754884), which explains how to extract it, but not how to extract upon uploading the zipped file. The code from there looks like:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) { |zip_file|
     zip_file.each { |f|
     f_path=File.join("destination_path", f.name)
     FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
     zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
   }
  }
```

Where should I place those particular lines of code (from the url I pasted above) in my program if they are compatible at all? Should it be in a `.erb` file or a `.rb` file, and if so, which one and how?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way just to test if your code works - you can process synchronously in controller after the model is saved successfully (in `create` action).

For most real scenarios where files can be large and take time to process - better way is to process asynchronously in background jobs, for that rails have [ActiveJob framework](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)