# Ruby - Get list of files from a binary stream which is a zip

Tags: ruby, zip

I am making a HTTP Get request to my web server . My server returns a .zip file as octet-stream . I am collecting it as bits in a variable say 'X'

Question is how do I from the variable 'X' get the list of files and their contents within zip without saving the contents of variable 'X' on disk.

I want to do all this in Ruby. Is it possible.

Comment: this may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204423/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the rubyzip gem,
you can use [Zip::InputStream](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/1.1.7/Zip/InputStream), which accepts StringIO objects.
Your HTTP response might already be a StringIO.

You could also use the [Tempfile](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) class from the standard library if the file-creating idiom is easier. These tempfiles are handled by the interpreter:

> "When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted. This means that’s it’s unnecessary to explicitly delete a Tempfile after use..."