# How to read an http stream and write it to a file with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using the form-data module from node I have submitted a zip file to a rails backend. I have no idea how to turn my data into a file once it reaches the destination. If you are wondering why the heck would someone submit a form built with node to a rails back end, well its because of electron! I'm building a desktop application and I need to push things to an existing backend that is built on rails. I have spent 3 full work days trying to successfully post a zip file to a rails endpoint with no luck and I literally am running out of ideas (failure is not an option). how do I turn the buffer of data named 'data' into a zip file? I'd be happy to write the code myself if someone could point me to an applicable resource or tutorial, I havn't been able to find one myself yet. Thanks!

```
{
"attachment":{
  "_overheadLength":157,
  "_valueLength":0,
  "_lengthRetrievers":[
     null
  ],
  "writable":false,
  "readable":true,
  "dataSize":0,
  "maxDataSize":2097152,
  "pauseStreams":true,
  "_released":false,
  "_streams":[
     "----------------------------860185489573893683941879\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"app.zip\"; filename=\"app.zip\"\r\nContent-Type: application-zip\r\n\r\n",
     {
        "source":{
           "_readableState":{
              "objectMode":false,
              "highWaterMark":65536,
              "buffer":[
                 {
                    "type":"Buffer",
                    "data":[
                       80,
                       181
                    ]
                 }
              ],
              "length":65536,
              "pipes":null,
              "pipesCount":0,
              "flowing":false,
              "ended":false,
              "endEmitted":false,
              "reading":false,
              "sync":false,
              "needReadable":false,
              "emittedReadable":true,
              "readableListening":false,
              "defaultEncoding":"utf8",
              "ranOut":false,
              "awaitDrain":0,
              "readingMore":false,
              "decoder":null,
              "encoding":null
           },
           "readable":true,
           "domain":null,
           "_events":{

           },
           "_eventsCount":3,
           "path":"/Users/guest/Library/Application Support/foundation-apps-template/app.zip",
           "fd":299,
           "flags":"r",
           "mode":438,
           "autoClose":true
        },
        "dataSize":0,
        "maxDataSize":null,
        "pauseStream":true,
        "_maxDataSizeExceeded":false,
        "_released":false,
        "_bufferedEvents":[

        ],
        "_events":{

        },
        "_eventsCount":1
     },
     null
  ],
  "_currentStream":null,
  "_boundary":"--------------------------860185489573893683941879"
```

}
    }

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204423/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Not relevant because it uses File.open on an existing File object. When I tried File.open it didn't seem to work. I'm trying to figure out how to turn what I have (a stream) into a zip file.